# DynamoDB tables programatic creation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local, nosql

Is there a framework/tool which I could use in order to separate the database table creation from the business logic for DynamoDB? In the RDBMS world a tool like Liquibase would do the trick.

Any thoughts ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **AWS CloudFormation** to create the DynamoDB table. Here is the [link](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/DynamoDB_Table.template) which has the DynamoDB create template.

AWS CloudFormation simplifies provisioning and management on AWS.

> AWS CloudFormation gives developers and systems administrators an easy
>   way to create and manage a collection of related AWS resources,
>   provisioning and updating them in an orderly and predictable fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamobee is a fork of mongobee, like a Liquibase, but use annotations in Java Classes. Available at https://github.com/dynamobee/dynamobee